# Regex not working as required

Tags: python, html, regex

Here is my HTML code:

```
<ul class="hide menuSearchType">
    <li><a href="../../dynamic/city_select.aspx">Search by city</a></li>
    <li><a href="../../searchbyphone.aspx">Search by phone</a></li>
    <li><a href="../searchbyaddress.aspx">Search by address</a></li>
    <li><a href="../searchbybrand.aspx">Search by brand</a></li>
    <li><a href="/advertisement-center/">Advertise with us</a></li>
    <li><a href="/advertisement-center/">Advertise with us</a></li>
    <li><a href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">Find a Person</a></li>
    <li><a href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">Find a Person</a></li>
    <li><a href="dynamic/city_select.aspx">Search by city</a></li>
    <li><a href="searchbybrand.aspx">Search by brand</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my Python code:

```
import re, os
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url = "http://www.phonebook.com.pk/dynamic/search.aspx?searchtype=cat&class_id=2566" 

path = urlparse(url)
lpath = os.path.dirname(path.path)

html = u"<ul class=\"hide menuSearchType\">\n    <li><a href=\"../../dynamic/city_select.aspx\">Search by city</a></li>\n    <li><a href=\"../../searchbyphone.aspx\">Search by phone</a></li>\n    <li><a href=\"../searchbyaddress.aspx\">Search by address</a></li>\n    <li><a href=\"../searchbybrand.aspx\">Search by brand</a></li>\n    <li><a href=\"/advertisement-center/\">Advertise with us</a></li>\n    <li><a href=\"/advertisement-center/\">Advertise with us</a></li>\n    <li><a href=\"//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans\">Find a Person</a></li>\n    <li><a href=\"//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans\">Find a Person</a></li>\n    <li><a href=\"dynamic/city_select.aspx\">Search by city</a></li>\n    <li><a href=\"searchbybrand.aspx\">Search by brand</a></li>\n</ul>"

linkList1 = re.findall(re.compile(u'(?<=href=")../.*?(?=")'), str(html))

for link1 in linkList:
    html = re.sub(link1, path.scheme + "://" + os.path.normpath(path.netloc + os.path.abspath(lpath + "/" + link1)), str(html))

print (html)
```

Problem is it detects the links with "../" as intended but also "../../" is changed, is there any way I can restrict my regex to just pick the url's with single "../"?

Expected output:

```
<ul class="hide menuSearchType">
    <li><a href="../../dynamic/city_select.aspx">Search by city</a></li>
    <li><a href="../../searchbyphone.aspx">Search by phone</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.phonebook.com.pk/searchbyaddress.aspx">Search by address</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.phonebook.com.pk/searchbybrand.aspx">Search by brand</a></li>
    <li><a href="/advertisement-center/">Advertise with us</a></li>
    <li><a href="/advertisement-center/">Advertise with us</a></li>
    <li><a href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">Find a Person</a></li>
    <li><a href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">Find a Person</a></li>
    <li><a href="dynamic/city_select.aspx">Search by city</a></li>
    <li><a href="searchbybrand.aspx">Search by brand</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please, use a parser instead of regexes...

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Dear Sir I am not allowed to use anything other than regex. My company's restriction.

Comment: That doesn't apply here, when you hear from you boss that he has right to do whatever he wants.

Comment: can you post you expected output so that I can give u better solution with regex

Comment: @akashkarothiya added expected output.

Comment: @akashkarothiya but in reality it changes the "../../" links as well.

Comment: I guess I am little late :)

Comment: @akashkarothiya No you are absolutely not, I have already found a problem with selected answer.

Comment: @akashkarothiya Please do answer, I would love to have a little help here as I am stuck for many hours.

Comment: I have already posted the answer, please check. instead of finding all regex, you can simply replace html variable with my regex, it will sove your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Using BeautifulSoup as requested :

```
from bs4 import Beautifulsoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
all = soup.select('li')
for i in all:
    try:
        output = re.sub(r'(?is)(href="../)([^.])','http://www.phonebook.com.pk/'+r'\2',str(i))
    except:
        output = i
    print(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace string using regex,

```
output = re.sub(r'(?is)(href="../)([^.])','http://www.phonebook.com.pk/'+r'\2',str(html))
```

Comment: I'll try after @GiftZwergrapper method.

Comment: It is also selecting the first "s" after "/" in both links

Comment: regex is working well but in python code it is giving odd output.

Comment: can you show me how to do this in BS4, I would be thankful, regex won't solve the problem, the only reason I was not using BS4 is because its slow and I am not used to it.

Comment: Here you go, see below answer

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following:

```
linkList1 = re.findall(re.compile(u'(?<=href=")../\w.*?(?=")'), str(html))
```

That guarantees that there has to be a word character after the slash.

Comment: thank you, you solved my problem that took me like 10+ hours to test different things.

Comment: No problem, but you should consider using a parser instead of regex, even though your boss doesn't like it.

Comment: @Giftwergrapper Okay, I'll try to convince him.

Comment: regex is working well but in python code it is giving odd output.